# How to maintain the old input value in checkbox after validating by an update request using laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, validation, input, checkbox

when i open the edit page it should have the value from the database and when i change the value and if in case validaton fails, i need the {{old('input')}} value to persist.
This is the code :

```
<input type="checkbox" id="show_in_website" name="show_in_website"  @if($data->show_in_website=='1') checked @endif>Show in Website
```

Comment: Is that code not working?

Comment: _Small Aside, not an answer_ I think you probably want to set the `value="{{$data->show_in_website}}"` to a specific thing and NOT whatever `show_in_website` is set to

Comment: Do you mean that you want to keep it in the state it was when you submit the form, and if the validation failed?

Comment: when i open the edit page it should have the value from the database and when i change the value and if in case validaton fails, i need the {{old('input')}} value to persist

Comment: @RoshJ just add `value="1"` to your input and you will be fine

Comment: @N69S Well we agree on that part at least. That is what my comment said... Dont do `value="{{$data->show_in_website}}"`

Comment: @RiggsFolly he's not setting any value in his input.

Comment: @N69S Forget it, my comment suggested that he do EXACTLY what you are suggesting and coded in your answer... i,e, `value="1"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do using the `old()` helper method. The `old()` helper method supports retrieving any old form value on validation failure. Also, it allows passing a default value on empty/null which means we can pass a value from our database as default when the edit page is initially called.

```
<input type="checkbox" id="show_in_website" name="show_in_website" {{ old('show_in_website', $data->show_in_website) ? 'checked' : '' }}> Show in Website
```

also, make sure you are redirecting back to the form with `withInput()` as:

```
if($validator->fails()) {
    return back()->withErrors($validator)->withInput();
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot :)Your Code is working , i tried this already but wasnt working fine,  may be i had some error, thanks again for the help

Comment: You might have missed calling ``withInput();`` No worries, we also make mistakes but as time goes on, we learn. :)

Comment: Yup, also i think without the validator failure check, it is working fine